# Is a specific mixed model within the class of models generated by lme4?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Given $i = 1, ..., n$ people, we measure a continuous response $y$, a `group` $g = 1, ..., G$ and a `class` $c = 1,2$. All members of a `group` $g$ are in the same `class`. There is dependence within each `group`, and the amount of dependence is determined by the `class`.

For example, the factors could be taken when there are 8 observations as

```
class <- as.factor(c(1,1, 1,1, 2,2, 2,2))
group <- as.factor(c(1,1, 2,2, 3,3, 4,4))
```

These specifications would produce the design matrices

```
Z1 <- rbind(c(1,0),
            c(1,0),
            c(0,1),
            c(0,1),
            c(0,0),
            c(0,0),
            c(0,0),
            c(0,0))

Z2 <- rbind(c(0,0),
            c(0,0),
            c(0,0),
            c(0,0),
            c(1,0),
            c(1,0),
            c(0,1),
            c(0,1))
```

and the response

```
y <- Z1 %*% rnorm(2, 0, s) + Z2 %*% rnorm(2, 0, t) + rnorm(8, 0, e)
```

where `s^2` is the variance of the random effect for the first class, `t^2` is the variance of the random effect for the second class, and `e^2` is the variance of the error term.

Assuming the variables satisfy these assumptions, is it possible to fit this random effect structure in `lme4`? An interpretation of this model is that there's a different random effect for different subsets of the data, which doesn't seem to be supported. Is there a mathematical maneuver to express this "different subsets have different random effects" condition as an equivalent condition which is expressible within the class of models `lme4` considers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want

```
dd <- data.frame(y,class,group)
library(lme4)
ff <- y ~ (0+dummy(class,"1")|group) + (0+dummy(class,"2")|group)
lFormula(ff, data=dd)$reTrms$Ztlist
```

This produces:

```
$`0 + dummy(class, "1") | group`
4 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 1 1 . . . . . .
2 . . 1 1 . . . .
3 . . . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .

$`0 + dummy(class, "2") | group`
4 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . . . . . . . .
2 . . . . . . . .
3 . . . . 1 1 . .
4 . . . . . . 1 1
```

There are empty columns in each individual element (for the groups that aren't represented within a class), but I think this is harmless ... I would try simulating some larger examples to see if they return the expected/true values.

The nested structure `(1|class) + (1|class|group)` (= `(1|class/group)`) might be equivalent ...

Comment: This works wonderfully: thank you!

Comment: What does lmer(y~0+(class|group), data=dd) do? This was initially what I tried and I naively would have thought it would be equivalent to the model specification that you provided

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want to consider the interaction between `class` and `group` as your grouping factor for which you assume only random intercepts. Hence, you could try something along these lines:

```
lmer(y ~ 1 + (1 | class:group), data = <your_data>)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that only estimates one variance component beyond the error variance, so it can't be right

Answer (score 2):

Since you say

> All members of a group g are in the same class

it appears that you have a nested structure, so you could fit

```
lmer(y ~ 1 +  (1 | class) + (1 | class:group), data = mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks! Here, `group` is well-defined without reference to `class` due to the coding, so there's no need to nest. When running this, the implied RE design matrix (gotten via `getME(mod, "Z")`) has 6 columns instead of 4, so isn't the correct specification.

Comment: These factors *are* nested. You have specified this with the encoding, so you can either specify the random effects as I said in my answer, or with `(1|class) + (1|group)` which is equivalent. I think the reason that getME returns a matrix with 6 columns is that `lmer` adds 2 columns of 1s to represent the intercepts for each class. Otherwise they are the same.

Comment: Thanks again for responding! I only mentioned that the variables are coded they way they do since the (I think only) motivation in your post was that the variables were nested. Ignoring the nesting, like you respond in your comment, you're suggesting doing a random effect version of a "two-way anova". To comment on this, I clarified that the design matrix this model gives is wrong. After Ben Bolker's answer, I did a simulation, and the fit of this two way modelis singular and gives random effects which are from the truth, so it can't be right. Thanks again!

Comment: For what it's worth, another (perhaps clearer) way to see that this may not be quite right is to imagine what this would do when there's in fact $3$ classes: here this solution would give only two variance components, instead of three as would be wanted.